# How to solve "The data types varchar and date are incompatible in the add operator." problelm

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
DECLARE @date AS DATE=GETDATE()
IF @date=CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
PRINT'This is Todatys date'  + @date 
GO
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tag it with the RDBMS you're using (my guess would be MS SQL server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message says, you can't add (`+`) a `varchar` and a `date`. You'll need to explicitly cast the `date` to a `varchar` in order to concatenate them:

```
PRINT 'This is Todays date'  + CAST(@date AS VARCHAR)
```

Comment: I would never rely on `CAST()` with date/time values... This culture dependant and the output wil vary with the executing system. I'd use `CONVERT()`, always together with the third parameter...